# Is it possible to rearrange a heroes skills?

Tags: darkest-dungeon

I'm not sure if this option doesn't exist, or if I'm just being dense, but I'm not able to re-arrange the order a heroes skills appear in the skillbar. I could have sworn I did this a few months back when the game was still in early access, but I can't figure it out now.

Can I rearrange the order of skills in the skillbar, and if so, how?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to disable all the skills and then enable them back in the order you want. That's the only way.